# How to find the max-ID by using a lambda-query?

Tags: c#, linq

I wanna find the next ID (ID_Titel) by selecting ID_Artiest. I try it by using LINQ (lambda-query). What do I do wrong.

By example:

[image]

For ID_Artiest 2, I wanna have ID_Titel n+1.

First I try it without .DefaultIfEmpty(). and then I get a message: **Sequence Contains No Element**

Second I try it with .DefaultIfEmpty().: And then I get the message: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

This is the source:

```
private void UpdateTitel(NoteringDataType itemDezeWeek)
...
...
    TitelDataType titel = new TitelDataType();
    if (Titelslijst.Count > 0)
        titel.ID_Titel = Titelslijst.Where(t => t.ID_Artiest == itemDezeWeek.ID_Artiest).OrderBy(t => t.ID_Titel).DefaultIfEmpty().Max(t => t.ID_Titel) + 1;
    else
        titel.ID_Titel = 1;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have an `itemDezeWeek.ID_Artiest` in your DB?

Comment: I have edit it. itemDezeWeek is an object with a parameter ID_Artiest. And the data comes from an Excel-workbook. But that doesn't mind.

Comment: Check what your `Titelslijst.Where(t => t.ID_Artiest == itemDezeWeek.ID_Artiest)` query returns, seems like the problem is there.

Comment: t.ID_Artiest <=> 1 and itemDezeWeek.ID_Artiest <=> 2, and then? The result has to be 0 + 1. (for ID_Artiest <=> 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the errors you got are expected if the first `Where` doesn't find any matching values.

Please try this:

```
titel.ID_Titel = Titelslijst.Where(t => t.ID_Artiest == itemDezeWeek.ID_Artiest)
                            .Select(t => t.ID_Titel)
                            .OrderByDescending(t => t)
                            .FirstOrDefault() + 1;
```

Since the `Select` transforms the collection to an enumeration of `int`s (I am assuming), the `.FirstOrDefault()` should return `0` if the `Where()` didn't return any matches. In your code, `.DefaultIfEmpty()` would have returned an `IEnumerable<T>` containing `null` because it was called on an enumeration of whatever `Titelslijst` contains.

Comment: That looks really cool! And since OP applies Max to `ID_Titel` and then adds 1 to the result, it is safe to assume the field is an integer

Comment: @Andrei Thanks. :) I think yours is actually more readable (+1 to you), but this does get it all done in one statement.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the errors you see happen when nothing in the list matches your `where` condition. `DefaultIfEmpty` in this case will give you just a single list with `null`, which does not help a lot.

To avoid such situations you should really assign ID to 1 if there no entries found. So the logic should be like:

```
TitelDataType titel = new TitelDataType();
int id = 1;
if (Titelslijst.Count > 0)
{
    var titles = Titelslijst.Where(t => t.ID_Artiest == itemDezeWeek.ID_Artiest);
    if (titles.Any())
        id = titles.Max(t => t.ID_Titel) + 1;
}

titel.ID_Titel = id;
```

Comment: Considering what OP says, if `!titles.Any()` then `1` should be returned

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin, and it will be. Well, not returned, but assigned.

Answer (score -1):

More short, more right:

```
Titelslijst.Where(t => t.ID_Artiest == itemDezeWeek.ID_Artiest).Select(t => t.ID_Artiest).Max();
```